# Install elm package with a specifying version?

Tags: elm

I am doing an Elm's tutorial. By that, the package `elm/http` is version `1.0.0`. But when I installed, the current version is `2.0.0`. And I don't how to install the package with a specifying version(here is `elm/http 1.0.0`).

I tried to modify the version of `elm/http` package to `1.0.0` in `elm.json` and then re-install with `elm install elm/http` but It's not working.

In JavaScript, I use `npm i thePackage@1.0.0` to do that.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried deleting `elm-stuff` folder before attempting to re-install version 1.0.0?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Elm 0.19, `elm install <package>` just updates your `elm.json` file, there is no local installation of the packages.  So updating the field in `elm.json` to `1.0.0` should be all that you need to do.  `elm make` will see that and use the right package.